# How to zip file after getting files from storage?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to zip files from list?

Path of my list:

```
files[index].path;
```

Flutter archive package code:

```
 final sourceDir = Directory("source_dir");
 final files = [
  File(sourceDir.path + "file1"),
   File(sourceDir.path + "file2")
  ];
  final zipFile = File("zip_file_path");
   try {
    ZipFile.createFromFiles(
     sourceDir: sourceDir, files: files, zipFile: zipFile);
     } catch (e) {
      print(e);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

By using this package [flutter_archive: ^5.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive) you can zip file after getting files from storage